# Need an algorithm for square root that provides a "remainder"

Tags: java, biginteger, sqrt

I'm writing a calculator without using decimals (supports only Rational numbers), but I'd like to be able to do a version of square root.

When a square root function is pressed for (say) the number 12, I'd like to just simplify/"reduce" the square root and return 2*sqrt(3)--by it into (2*2) * 3 and extracting the sqrt(2*2) as 2.

I'm using biginteger which has a very nice gcd() method and a pow() method that is restricted to positive parameters (which makes sense unless you are trying to do exactly what I'm trying to do.

I could come up with a few iterative ways to do this but they may take a while with numbers in the hundreds-of-digits range.

I'm hoping there is some cute, simple, non-iterative trick I haven't been exposed to.

Just to clarify: I have the intent to add imaginary numbers so I'm planning on  results like this:

```
17 + 4i √3  
-----------  
     9
```

Without long streams of decimals.

Comment: I hope that you meant 2*sqrt(3) for the square root of 12.

Comment: Since for the vast majority of numbers this result may not be unique (or is it and I'm missing some obvious math theorem here? a bit late here ;) ), you'd have to specify your requirements a bit more clearly. Obviously you could use the factors of the number, but then that's a factorization problem and we all know how that turns out for large numbers.

Comment: Thanks @ted, I knew I'd do that somewhere!

Comment: @voo using the gcd() and isPrime() methods of BigInteger are amazingly fast for even pretty huge numbers.  I currently use them to reduce the fractions (I currently return results like 3 1/2 for 7/2 which requires a little factoring)

Comment: By the way, I was originally going to store my "Rational" as a collection of primes, each prime either above or below the fraction-bar.  This would have make this problem trivial and also made all fractions self-reducing, but gcd() turned out to be so fast that my solution of factoring it once and storing it factored seemed like premature optimization.

Comment: @Bill - I believe BigInteger's primality test method is named `isProbablyPrime`, which gives you an idea about what you're getting when you use it. It's a statistical test and does not give a definitive answer. Perhaps the _a priori_ prime factor representation wasn't a premature optimization after all. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking, in essence, is to find all repeated prime factors. Since you're dealing with numbers in the hundreds-of-digits range, I'm going to venture a guess here that there are no good ways to do this in general. Otherwise public key cryptography will all of a sudden be on somewhat shaky ground.

There are a number of [methods of computing the square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). With those, you can express the result as an integer **plus** a remainder less than 1.

Comment: All the methods of computing a square root seemed to be based on returning a number very close to the square root.  For example 578 should return 2*sqr(17) not some number near 24

Comment: That's why you need the [unique prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) of the number.

Comment: Yep, guess there is no easy solution.  I'll wait a bit longer but you're probably right, I'm just going to have to go with factoring and looking for pairs.  Good news is this same method would solve cube roots :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try finding the highest perfect square that is less than your number.  That will give you part of the equation, then you would only need to handle the remainder part which is the difference between your number and the perfect square you found.  This would degrade as numbers get large as well, but perhaps not as fast.

Comment: Hmm, intuitively I don't think this would work.  The highest perfect square less than my number may not be a factor of my number which would mean it couldn't be used and I'd have to go to the next highest square (the iterative solution I was trying to avoid)

Comment: Good point, completely spaced out on the factor.  You would have to include that which doesn't gain you much.  Other than some basic optimizations I'm not sure there is much you can do.